# Working around the "You don't currently have permission to access this folder" issue for PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell-4.0, userappdatapath

When navigating to `C:\Users\%SomeUsername%` as an administrator on a Windows 2008 R2 server I get the error `You don't currently have permission to access this folder`, `Click Continue to permanently get access to this folder`.  Clicking `Continue` resolves this problem.

If I try the same by PowerShell (e.g. `get-childitem 'C:\Users\' -Directory | get-childitem -Force`; or some variant), any profiles to which I've not already granted myself access explicitly give the error `Access to the path 'C:\Users\%SomeUsername%' is denied.`; even with the Force switch included.

Is there a way to "click continue" via PowerShell; i.e. have the system give me access to anything which I don't strictly have access to, though as an administrator on the server can grant myself access to.  Ideally this would be done as I access the files (e.g. by a switch on the `Get-Item` command) rather than having to code something to explicitly go through all files checking and amending permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure about start Powershell Run As Admin if you want always run it as administrator make shortcut from powershell.exe and follow this image : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My mistake; I hadn't been running the PowerShell session as administrator (i.e. UAC).

- right click on powershell.exe
- run as administrator